# Using __init__ values from another class

Tags: python

```
class Class1:
  def __init__(self, list1, list2, list3):
    self.arg1= list1
    self.arg2= list2
    self.arg3= list3
```

Above is my first class, and below is my second class. I'm trying to use the values assigned in the first class within my second class. I want to add two of the values together in class 2 then add that to a new value.

```
class Class2(Class1):
    def __init__(self,Class1):

        self.arg1 = class1.list1
        self.arg2 = class1.list2
        self.arg3 = class1.list3
        self.arg4 = arg4

def calc(self, Class1):
    for row in Class1.list1:
        self.arg4.append(Class1.list2 + Class1.list3)

callF = Class2(class1).calc(Class1)
```

When I call run this code I'm getting the error attributeError: type object 'class1' has no attribute 'list1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the arguments `list1`, `list2` etc. from `Class1` initializer in `Class2`. IMO you should access them using the variables `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3` as follows. Notice the change `self.arg1 = Class1.arg1` instead of using `self.arg1 = Class1.list1`. I also added a `return` statement for `arg4` and initialized it as an empty list because it was missing in your code.

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, list1, list2, list3):
        self.arg1= list1
        self.arg2= list2
        self.arg3= list3

class Class2(Class1):
    def __init__(self, Class1):
        self.arg1 = Class1.arg1
        self.arg2 = Class1.arg2
        self.arg3 = Class1.arg3
        self.arg4 = []

    def calc(self, Class1):
        for row in Class1.arg1:
            self.arg4.append(Class1.list2  + Class1.list3)
        return self.arg4    

c1 = Class1([],[],[])            
callF = Class2(c1).calc(c1)
```

You also had indentation error and typos (lower case class name) in your code.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I wasn't sure how to fix the indentation, I rewrote some of it in the question for easier reading

Comment: Calling the function is causing an issue with this, attributeError: 'Class2' object has no attribute 'calc'

Answer (score 0):

Class1 is a type, it's not an instance. First create an instance of your object.

But you also have a problem because you want `Class2` to inherit from `Class1` without really using this inheritance.

So clarify what you want to do on a piece of paper and the interactions between the objects. Perhaps `Class2` should have a member variable of type `Class1`. If so, do it like that.

```
class Class2():
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.arg1 = c.list1
        self.arg2 = c.list2
        self.arg3 = c.list3
        self.arg4 = arg4 # where does this one come from?

    def calc(self, c):
        for row in c.list1:
            self.arg4.append(c.list2 + c.list3)

c = Class1([], [], [])
callF = Class2(c).calc(c)
```

Comment: `def calc(self, c):` should be indented to be be inside `Class2`